# how to create a custom page in child theme or plugin?

Tags: plugins, child-theme

i'm kind of new to plugins .

for a project we need to create a special form which normal plugin won't help us .
we should create a special form page which insert data to db .
the main problem is because of limit of modification of main theme i can not directly do changes i want.
my question was is there any way to create that custom page template using plugin or child theme ?

every answers will be welcomed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to copy a Page Template from the Parent Theme into your Child Theme and rename that template with the new which you want to set into the site or create a new template PHP file add below code:

```
<?php /*

Template Name: -- Template Name --

*/​

get_header();


get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro : )

Comment: Welcome bro : ), can you please vote on the answer. @hosseinkhosromanesh